# Maven tests are executed when run from Eclipse but not from command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I have added all dependencies and surefire plugin. so it is executing successfully in eclipse(via TestNG) but when run through command prompt (mvn clean, mvn compile, mvn test) it doesn't throw any error nor it executes my project. below is the attached screenshot. and the pom.xml file.

Please let me know where am i going wrong

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DyNG.png)

[POM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ohlj.png)

[TestNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gSng.png)

Comment: Build success. Do you expect anything better?

Comment: But my test cases are not getting executed which i am trying to run from Maven. Am not able to figure it out, why my test cases are not getting executed.

Comment: `Maven` got nothing to compile. Perhaps your `testng` binaries wasn't invoked at all.

Comment: But my tests are getting successfully executed from eclipse when i am running it as TestNG suite

Comment: Can you include the surefire plugin portion of the POM. test class names are not matching the defaults which are picked automatically - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html. You will need to specifically include them in the surefire plugin. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html. Or include the suiteXmlFiles setting in surefire plugin in pom which maybe the easiest way.

Comment: Seriously!....Thanks....It worked......from last  two days i was cracking my head on it.

Comment: Where are the test classes are located? They should be located in `src/test/java` and named like `*Test.java`...furthermore you have to be aware that you have a dependency on TestNG (scope: test)...Do not use suites..Just let Maven handle that....Apart from that you don't need to define includes cause maven-surefire-plugin already as default includes so keep the convention over configuration. Remove the testng.xml file...not needed..